# How to get mathbb{1} to work in beamer? (or similar alternative)

Tags: beamer

Idk why beamer thinks changing \mathbb{1} to what it does is a good idea, but how do I get it back?

Comment: You can also use \mathds{1} from \usepackage{dsfont}, which looks similar but is not pixelated.

Comment: @Alan Phelype Olein  barbara Zarko  this is about getting bold letters withing the beamer framework that is many things cannot be changed easily.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat  how do I do bold 0?

idk wtf designed these fonts

Comment: For a **bold** (as opposed to double-stroke) zero `0` you can use `$\boldsymbol{0}$` from `\usepackage{amsmath}` or `$\bm{0}$` from `\usepackage{bm}`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat  sorry I meant double stroke 0  \mathds{0} is just nothing